# A BFE registry key's ACL is flagged by Microsoft Attack Surface Analyzer - what do I need to do?

Tags: windows, vulnerability-scanners, configuration, threat-mitigation

Can anyone help me to understand what kind of action I should take to mitigate this issue, which emerged from Microsoft Surface Attack Analyzer? How I can tighten the ACL? Is there a standard procedure to do?

```
Service BFE is vulnerable to tampering by multiple non-administrator accounts.
Description:

The service BFE is vulnerable to tampering by multiple non-administrator accounts.

Details:

Service: BFE
Registry keys writable by: 

Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\services\BFE\Parameters\Policy\Persistent\Callout

Account Rights
NT SERVICE\BFE (S-1-5-80-1383140227-27657646-1662666058-2710981023-2300958487)  KEY_SET_VALUE
Local Service (S-1-5-19)    WRITE_DAC

Action:

The relevant ACL(s) must be tightened.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says that this critical-for-security registry key is writeable by `Local Service (S-1-5-19)    WRITE_DAC`, which is a key security risk. Its ACL should be changed to administrator level group or users using the security tab for this key in regedit. Alternatively, you could simply remove this WRITE, as you never know what kind of integrity feature it is. With one bad ACL you can compromise the complete OS.